# How to print or save the output values of each layer of neural network in Theano?

Tags: theano

I need to examine the output values of each layer of the network in theano-python.

I suppose : net.layers[i].output should do the job.

However, it seems  net.layers[i].output is theano.tensor type.  How to print it or save it in some file format can be read by human ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
net.layers[i].output.get_values()
```

to convert the tensor values into the Numpy array.

And subsequently, you use the following to store those values:

```
numpy.savetxt
```